# Sci-Fi moderator on AI content strike

Tags: discussion, moderation, stackexchange

As some of you may be aware a new policy came into effect recently, whereby moderators network wide were told to not moderate new content on the site solely on the basis of it being AI generated.

If not, here is [an article](https://devclass.com/2023/06/05/stack-overflow-volunteer-moderators-down-tools-over-secret-new-policy-that-obstructs-removal-of-ai-generated-content/) about the situation to catch you up to speed.

And while this is more of a Stack Overflow problem, I'm both striking in solidarity with moderators across the network and because we have a problem with what are considered low quality posts but not **very** low quality posts generated by AI tools like ChatGPT, mainly on [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-id) posts.

The reason this is a particular issue is, that to the untrained eye these are simply *technically* wrong answers, which we get plenty of but don't deserve deletion simply by being wrong, at least not if they're well intentioned and have put some effort in.

The new policy essentially tells us to leave their moderation to non-diamond moderators, who don't have the same tools to detect patterns of abuse that mark these out as different from regular users trying (and sometimes failing) to answer questions earnestly.

So I've signed (with my SE oauth login) [this list of moderators on strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/), and I'm downing moderator tools until we come to a better agreement with the company running the network.

---

Caveats.

I will be the first to admit, I'm not the most active mod on the site, but I am still striking out if principle.

Secondly, please hold me to this! If I slip into moderating habits on autopilot please call me out!

Comment: There's also the [official MSE strike post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/244695), the [official strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) and [my breakdown of what lead up to this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979/2370483)

Comment: @Valorum just me currently

Comment: @Valorum: Note that people without diamonds are also welcome to participate in the strike. I signed it even though I rarely bother with review queues and such, mostly out of solidarity, but I do intend to cease voting on all main (non-meta) sites.

Comment: And my axe! AI may be helpful in certain applications but I don't think expert Q&A is one of them.

Comment: You have my support and appreciation for honoring the strike.  I signed the petition even though I've not got a diamond.

Comment: After reading Machavity's breakdown of what happened and the strike letter, I've decided to add my name too; for what my name is worth anyway.

Comment: I guess its that time of year again when stackexchange becomes dramaexchange. I would have liked it if this site had stayed out of it, but it itself isn't really known for being drama free so, what do I know? Go at it everyone, have fun

Comment: I find it a bit harsh to call it a drama though. Sure, the reaction of some can be considered as extreme, such as the one you noticed on Academia. From my point of view though, the problem is the fact the moderators are being denied the right to moderate to some extent.

Comment: If you want to have a long in depth discussion on the merits or not of the strike/SE’s position in this whole thing can we take it to one of the main meta posts? We don’t really need to reiterate it all here again. This is just an informational post for one mod’s stake in the strike.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Are you still on strike following the MSE post, [Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/162827)?

Comment: @galacticninja I'll be back soon. I wasn't planning on announcing it though

Comment: Should we tag this [meta-tag:status-completed] when you're back? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I can't speak for anyone else who went on strike, but I'm back now 